# /usr/bin/ld: crtbegin.o: No such file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang, llvm

I want to install llvm-clang but have no root access at work. many of our packages are outdated so I am installing everything locally under my home directory.

I installed cmake and gcc but now having errors when installing llvm.

I have my home directory structured this way:

```
~/gcc_build -> has the /bin directory which includes gcc, g++...etc (result of make install).

~/gcc-7.1.0 -> which has the main gcc build directory (where make was run)

~/llvm-4.0.0.src -> the main llvm directory 

~/llvm_make -> where I am trying to make llvm in (empty)
```

This is my command:

```
    [server-01:llvm_make]% ../cmake-3.8.2/bin/cmake ../llvm-4.0.0.src -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/sbay/gcc_build/bin/g++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/sbay/gcc_build/bin/gcc
```

But I am getting this error:

```
[server-01:llvm_make]% ../cmake-3.8.2/bin/cmake ../llvm-4.0.0.src -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/sbay/gcc_build/bin/g++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/sbay/gcc_build/bin/gcc
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.1.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /home/sbay/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/sbay/gcc_build/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /whome/sbay/gcc_build/bin/gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /home/sbay/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
  The C compiler "/home/sbay/gcc_build/bin/gcc" is not able to
  compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /home/sbay/llvm_make/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_13e2f/fast"

  /usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_13e2f.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_13e2f.dir/build

  gmake[1]: Entering directory
  `/home/sbay/llvm_make/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_13e2f.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

  /home/sbay/gcc_build/bin/gcc -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_13e2f.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
  /home/sbay/llvm_make/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

  Linking C executable cmTC_13e2f

  /home/sbay/cmake-3.8.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_13e2f.dir/link.txt --verbose=1

  /home/sbay/gcc_build/bin/gcc
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_13e2f.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_13e2f

  /usr/bin/ld: crtbegin.o: No such file: No such file or directory

  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

  gmake[1]: *** [cmTC_13e2f] Error 1

  gmake[1]: Leaving directory
  `/home/sbay/llvm_make/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  gmake: *** [cmTC_13e2f/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:47 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/sbay/llvm_make/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/sbay/llvm_make/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I would highly appreciate any input.

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding --sysroot= option
e.g.--sysroot=/home/lz/olimex/gcc-4.3.3/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, so I added this --sysroot=/home/sbay/gcc-7.1.0 but got this error:

../cmake-3.8.2/bin/cmake ../llvm-4.0.0.src -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/sbay/gcc_build/bin/g++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/sbay/gcc_build/bin/gcc --sysroot=/home/sbay/gcc-7.1.0
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/sbay/llvm_make/--sysroot=/home/sbay/gcc-7.1.0" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI

Comment: My bad, I added -DCMAKE_SYSROOT=/home/sbay/gcc-7.1.0 instead and now the error is: /usr/bin/ld: this linker was not configured to use sysroots

Comment: I guess you have to find other gcc version or build with sysroot enabled

Comment: I have downloaded binutils now and building it. Do you think me using a local version of ld would work? How to build with sysroot enabled? I already did ./configure;make. Was that the wrong approach?

Comment: "Do you think me using a local version of ld would work?" If you have older version of local ld most probably it will not work. You have to add something like --with-sysroot to ./configure (check what options it has)